# linking upload image in firebase storage button with the submit button in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I developed a small form that submit information for a requests in firebase, that is going to submit a regular information in the database, and the image in storage.[! (see the design of the form for more clarity)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ylzz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ylzz.png)
as you see in the form, the button for submitting the image is different than the button of submitting regular information. How can I merge the two buttons?, so when I clicked submit button, it should submit the both the regular information and the image with the same ID so i can retrieve the requests later, I tried to merge the two methods together but it shows me an error.

Here are the two methods of the buttons:

```
    private void btnInsert1(){
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref1 = database.getReference("requests");
    DatabaseReference ref2=ref1.push();
    String id=ref2.getKey();
    request1 =new requests();
    getValues();
    ref1.child(id).setValue(request1);
    Toast.makeText(FillRequestPage.this,"Data inserted....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

 private void uploadImage() {
    if(filePath != null){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(FillRequestPage.this,"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(FillRequestPage.this,"Failed"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });

    }
}

private void chooseimage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            data != null && data.getData() != null )
    {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An error which is?

Comment: the app has stopped

Comment: Ok, but in the logcat, there is an error, which is?